# When zooming, <audio> object moves up from bottom and overlaps stuff on top

Tags: css, html5-audio

The following problem occurs for my `<audio>` tag with iOS Safari, Firefox and Dolphin browsers, but **not** on any OS browser = the audio control moves up with zooming+ and ultimately overlaps the object above it.

The static layout, no zooming, is great ... zooming throws everything over the cliff.

FWIW, I did mess with the meta "viewport" tag, but no luck.

`<audio>` object is at the bottom of the layout. It obeys my css code, except when I zoom. When I zoom via pinching out, the object moves up and overlaps the `<section>` above it.

```css
html {
    font-size: 20px;     /* baseline for all descendants */
    font-size: 2.5vw;
}

.caroler {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:  1.70em;
    color:      blue;

    padding-bottom: 1.0em;
}

.aSongControl {
    display: block;      /* center ... */

    margin: 0 auto;

    width:  90%;         /* squeeze width because of .content's rounded corners */

    font-size: 120%;     /* for non-support text ... */
    color:     #990099;
}

/*
    This is the audio control-specific Selector.
    Other Selectors handle position and sizing.
*/
audio {
    background-color: white;
}

#theSong {
    /*
        deliberately empty just to initialize
        certain <audio> parms, e.g., the volume
    */
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
Inside <body>

<section class="caroler">
as sung by an unknown Caroler<br>
in front of the White House<br>
on December 24th, 2018
</section>

 <audio id="theSong" class="aSongControl" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/Lafayette_Square.m4a" type="audio/mp4">
    <a href='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' title='Get Quicktime' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false'>
    Install Quicktime to hear this awesome Hymn
    </a><br>
 </audio>
<audio>
```

As General Custer probably yelled "HAALP!"

***NEW ADDITIONS TO OP:***

1) a reader below strongly urged to disable zooming via a small change to the `<meta>` tag. Easy enough, but I can only echo what another member of STO said "It's just not nice to disable zooming, especially for those who depend on this feature".

2) Anyway, let's press on. I have 'regressed' to using JS and ditched the Viewport units, vw and vh:

```
document.body.setScaledFont = function(f) {
    var s = this.offsetWidth, fs = s * f;
    this.style.fontSize = fs + '%';

    return this
};

document.body.setScaledFont(0.10);
window.onresize = function() {
    document.body.setScaledFont(0.10);
}
```

Guess what? The `<audio>` STILL MOVES UP and eventually covers the `<div>` immediately prior to the `<audio>`. This undeniably means that the use of **vw, vh** units are **not** the problem.

Here is a repeat of the code for the `<audio>` above:

```
 <audio id="theSong" class="aSongControl" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/Lafayette_Square.m4a" type="audio/mp4">
    <a href='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' title='Get Quicktime' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false'>
    Install Quicktime to hear this awesome Hymn
    </a><br>
 </audio>
<audio>
```

with:

```
.aSongControl {
    display: block;      /* center ... */

    margin: 0 auto;

    width:  90%;

    font-size: 120%;     /* for non-support text ... */
    color:     #990099;
}

audio {
    background-color: white;
}
```

At this point, I do not understand why I have to place the `class="aSongControl"` inside the `<audio>` tag in order to get the `<audio>` to fill the window's width via `width: 80%`

If I try:

```
<section class="aSongControl">
<audio id="theSong" controls preload="auto">
...
</audio>
</section>
```

there is no block centering and no window-filling, both of which are called for within `.aSongControl`.

I wish I knew the answer because just maybe this answer holds a clue as to why the `<audio>` control exhibits a mind of its own by mysteriously moving up and covering the `<div>` above the `<audio>`.

Again, no problem on OS browsers ... just the iOS browsers.

It's New Year's folks, take pity on me!

Comment: You should only develop for zoom level of `100%`. There is no reliable cross-browser method to get current zoom level, which means this information is not available inside `window` object, so you can't use it to adjust values of properties on your elements. Users zooming voluntarily give up viewing the layout as intended to get either readability or birds-eye-view, and that's controlled by browser (developers have no control over it).

Comment: But the relative positioning should not change.

Comment: And it all works as it should, except for iOS browsers. So, that’s the rub. And is there something unique about the last item??

Comment: What you posted cannot be used to create a [mcve]. Which makes it impossible for anyone to understand the problem you're describing, or to test any potential solution. Which element has `position:relative`?

Comment: FWIW = http://www.lovesongforever.com/whitehouse

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, Hope it will help.

```
<meta 
     name='viewport' 
     content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' 
/>
```

This will prevent user from zooming

Comment: You're very right. But, is that really a good idea? Just asking. Another thing ... After reading gobs and gobs about this, is there a genuine bug in iOS browsers with Viewport units, vw + vh.  And, if so, should I just suck it up and go @media

Comment: This is a goo idea, as at some pages user can not zoomin means, your elements are not moving, so you're not facing such issues.